# open source library for Optical mark reader

Tags: java, image-processing

I want a open source library for optical mark reading (OMR).Is there any such library?
I want to use this library with my java application.

Comment: A little more detail would help. What form is the input in? What is the structure of your "master" sheets, etc.

Comment: that is not yet decided, i wil decide the the type of form based on lib.but i prefer to use normal quality paer  as input.Structure of sheet will be once that suite the lib

Comment: Did you get an answer for this question? I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score -1):

zxing might of use for you, http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list, is a "Multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library". There are code samples for JavaSE, ME, Android, Blackberry, IPhone ....

Comment: thanks for replying.But zing library is for qrcode and barcode.it does not read omr

Comment: ok, my mistake didn't read full explanation of what OMR really is