# Can we search content(text) within images using plone 4.1?

Tags: python, plone

How can we search content(text) within images using plone 4.1. I work on linux Suppose an image say a sample.jpg contains text like 'Happy Birthday', on using search 'Birthday' I should get the contents i.e sample.jpg

Comment: You are a little short on details here. Could you explain what you expect? Uploading an image of text, then OCR the text and index the result?

Comment: The answer is no, not using Plone. You need to use other methods. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606274/algorithm-to-detect-presence-of-text-on-image) for ideas.

Comment: Perhaps you might actually post a link to the image you think should be indexable.  I disagree that the answer is flat out "no", though you'd need to write some code yourself, but certain kinds of images might be indexable (ie, as Martijn says, if you could get text via OCR, then the portal_transforms tool could make it possible to index; then there are image formats with metadata, which can also be indexed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to use collective.DocumentViewer with various options to select from

Answer (score 2):

Someone has done this before with Plone 3. I think the same approach should work with Plone 4.1 too.

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/ocr-in-plone-using-tesseract-ocr

-Matt