# Detect text in a scanned page

Tags: image-processing, split, coordinates, detection, scanning

I'm trying to detect the text in a scanned page and get the coordinates of it.
See the attached image for an example of scanned page.

I need the vertical coordinates for spliting page from the useless parts, and then detect the text's coordinates.

What kind of tools could I use to split and detect text's coordinates?

[image: Example of scanned page]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to detect presence of text on image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606274/algorithm-to-detect-presence-of-text-on-image)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Stroke Width Transform](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf).
See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608022/135862).

Comment: +1, thank you for pointing me at "Stroke wifht Transform", I will look at it. However my this case the pictures are not taken outdoor, in natural scene, but taken on a table with almost the same border and almost the same position.
SWT could interpretate text in left the page in my example and it's not correct. I will give it a try. Thank you

Comment: "fast"? Anyway, if you know where the page is then you might be able to find the white margins. The text would be inside the margins.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "almost". I didn't know the right position of the text, but I know that it will always be on the left or right page, like in the attached image. I try Scan Tailor software that split the image and detect the text rather good. I would like to know if there are some algorithms that I could implement in a workflow to get the coordinates of the text.