# Open-source Python tools for text detection

Tags: python, text, machine-learning, neural-network, ocr

Are there are any open-source projects that can be used to detect whether an image has text? It doesn't need to do OCR, just tell us whether there is a good probability that the image has text on it. My thought if I can't find one off-the-shelf is to build a CNN model to do the job, but I am assuming that this has already been done.

Comment: image recognition is hard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606274/algorithm-to-detect-presence-of-text-on-image

Answer (score 0):

You should check this repository:

https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python

and particularly :

https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#ocr