# How to detect paragraphs in a text document image for a non-consistent text structure in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to identify paragraphs of text in a `.pdf` document by first converting it into an image then using OpenCV. But I am getting bounding boxes on lines of text instead of paragraphs. How can I set some threshold or some other limit to get paragraphs instead of lines?

Here is the sample input image:

[image: input]

Here is the output I am getting for the above sample:

[image: output]

I am trying to get a single bounding box on the paragraph in the middle. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv) code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

large = cv2.imread('sample image.png')
rgb = cv2.pyrDown(large)
small = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(small, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# using RETR_EXTERNAL instead of RETR_CCOMP
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#For opencv 3+ comment the previous line and uncomment the following line
#_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
    mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 0
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, idx, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)

    if r > 0.45 and w > 8 and h > 8:
        cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 2)


cv2.imshow('rects', rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample image to debug as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy ways to detect and crop blocks (paragraphs) of text out of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174563/easy-ways-to-detect-and-crop-blocks-paragraphs-of-text-out-of-image)

Comment: One procedure could be to cluster all the bounding boxes based on adjacency. Sort the list of bounding boxes according to their starting y co-ordinate. If the difference between the ending y co-ordinate of a bounding box and the starting y coordinate of the immediate next bounding box is less than a certain threshold, you can cluster them as constituting a single paragraph.

Comment: @LazyCoder The link you provided can help but as I am not that much experienced in c++ or openCV I was not able to interpret the answer provided in that link.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev's solution is what you need bro. Good luck!

Comment: Blur the image a bit first and threshold so the lines of text in the middle come together, but do not span across the gap between paragraphs

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a classic situation for [dilate](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation). Whenever you want to connect multiple items together, you can dilate them to join adjacent contours into a single contour. Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/), convert to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary image.
2. **Connect adjacent words together.** We create a [rectangular kernel](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) and [dilate](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) to merge individual contours together.
3. **Detect paragraphs.** From here we [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), obtain the rectangular [bounding rectangle coordinates](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) and [highlight the rectangular contours](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html).

---

Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

Here's where the magic happens. We can assume that a paragraph is a section of words that are close together, to achieve this we dilate to connect adjacent words

[image]

Result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Create rectangular structuring element and dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours and draw rectangle
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you @nathancy, this is what I was looking for.