# Stroke Width Transform (SWT) implementation (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, simplecv

Can anyone describe how can i implement SWT in python using opencv or simplecv ?

Comment: if you are looking for a paper implementation, you could add a link to that paper, or atleast provide a link to what is SWT.

Comment: may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837124/stroke-width-transform-swt-implementation-java-c

Comment: i already saw them, but the link was broken,and no code or psudo code are available.

Comment: that link definitely works: https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia

Comment: @AruniRC,Thank you. please send your link as answer to i accept it.

Comment: A matlab implementation (based on C++ mex file) can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971599/1714410).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok so here goes:

The link that has details on the implementation with the code download link at the bottom: [SWT](https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia)

For the sake of completeness, also mentioning that SWT or Stroke Width Transform was devised by Epshtein and others in 2010 and has turned out to be one of the most successful text detection methods til date. It does not use machine learning or elaborate tests. Basically after Canny edge detection on the input image, it calculates the thickness of each stroke that makes up objects in the image. As text has uniformly thick strokes, this can be a robust identifying feature.

The implementation given in the link is using C++, OpenCV and the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library they use for the connected graph traversals etc. after the SWT step is computed. Personally I've tested it on Ubuntu and it works quite well (and efficiently), though the accuracy is not exact.

Answer (score 8):

I implemented something similar to the distance transform based SWT described in
'**ROBUST TEXT DETECTION IN NATURAL IMAGES WITH EDGE-ENHANCED MAXIMALLY STABLE EXTREMAL REGIONS** by *Huizhong Chen, Sam S. Tsai, Georg Schroth, David M. Chen, Radek Grzeszczuk, Bernd Girod*'.

It's not the same as described in the paper but a rough approximation that served my purpose. Thought I should share it so somebody might find it useful (and point out any errors/improvements). It is implemented in C++ and uses OpenCV.

```
    // bw8u : we want to calculate the SWT of this. NOTE: Its background pixels are 0 and forground pixels are 1 (not 255!)
    Mat bw32f, swt32f, kernel;
    double min, max;
    int strokeRadius;

    bw8u.convertTo(bw32f, CV_32F);  // format conversion for multiplication
    distanceTransform(bw8u, swt32f, CV_DIST_L2, 5); // distance transform
    minMaxLoc(swt32f, NULL, &max);  // find max
    strokeRadius = (int)ceil(max);  // half the max stroke width
    kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3)); // 3x3 kernel used to select 8-connected neighbors

    for (int j = 0; j < strokeRadius; j++)
    {
        dilate(swt32f, swt32f, kernel); // assign the max in 3x3 neighborhood to each center pixel
        swt32f = swt32f.mul(bw32f); // apply mask to restore original shape and to avoid unnecessary max propogation
    }
    // swt32f : resulting SWT image
```

Comment: The local maxima of the Distance Transform will yield the half-stroke width. That's a nice observation, although some papers in 2011-2012 used this exact thing in combination with region detectors like MSERs.

Comment: @AruniRC The paper in the given link provides details about this method. Actually this half stroke-width thing is not my observation. Really sorry if my writing makes it look like that it's mine. All the credit of this should go to the authors of this paper.

Comment: Oh, I did not mean it that way at all. Just an observation. And sorry, my fault for not seeing the ICIP paper link previously. In fact, using the distance transform to get the half-width is much more easy and elegant implementation-wise. Personally, I had used  a Laplacian operator to get the local extrema of dist. trans. image, but your way of dilating is cleaner.

Comment: The input image of your method must have a background value of zero and and a foreground value of one? How would I realize this?

Comment: @BastianSchoettle We apply SWT to a binary image, so you can use [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) with `maxval` set to `1` to create this binary image. Just an example.

Comment: Thank you...I was writing faster than thinking. I figured it out a couple minutes after posting the comment.

Answer (score 5):

There is a complete Library [SWTloc](https://github.com/ag-ds-bubble/swtloc) here a Python 3 implementation of the algorithm

---

**v2.0.0 onwards**

#### Install the library

```
pip install swtloc
```

#### Transforming Image

```py
import swtloc as swt
imgpath = 'images/path_to_image.jpeg'
swtl = swt.SWTLocalizer(image_paths=imgpath)
swtImgObj = swtl.swtimages[0]
swt_mat = swtImgObj.transformImage(text_mode='lb_df',
                                   auto_canny_sigma=1.0,
                                   maximum_stroke_width=20)
```

[image: Transform Display]

---

#### Localizing Letters

```py
localized_letters = swtImgObj.localizeLetters(minimum_pixels_per_cc=100,
                                              maximum_pixels_per_cc=10_000,
                                              acceptable_aspect_ratio=0.2)
```

[image: Letter Localizations]

---

#### Localizing Words

```py
localized_words = swtImgObj.localizeWords()
```

[image]

Full Disclosure : I am the author of this library