# How to extract the characters of the area

Tags: opencv, ocr

[image]
[image]

I want to know that how to extract the characters efficiently in my pictures.

Comment: StackOverflow is for help with coding problems - have you written any code (to try solve your problem) which isn't working?

Comment: I would suggest starting with stroke width transform algorithm : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116199/stroke-width-transform-swt-implementation-python