# Crop rectangular area in opencv

Tags: opencv, crop

i am able to detect text areas in an image and i am marking those areas by rectangle.I followed the link [text extraction from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv) to do this.
Can anyone suggest a way I can crop the detected areas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to crop the image;

```
Rect roi(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
Mat image_roi = image(roi);
image_roi.copyTo(cropimage);
imwrite("cropimage.jpg",image_roi);
```

Comment: i am getting the whole text area as the output, is there some way by which i can get each letter segmented in an image?

Comment: For that you need to find each letter and then get bounding rect of the letter and crop as per above procedure.
This looks somewhat similar to your problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python