# Detecting Text Regions from image using EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr, emgucv

I am new to EmguCV and OpenCV. I want to detect the text Regions from an Image using EmguCV.

There are already some solutions posted on Stack using OpenCV.

1. [Extracting text OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv?lq=1)

But unable to convert that OpenCV code to EmguCV.

Comment: See [text detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html). You may need to install the latest EmguCV version

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct conversion of the accepted answer in the link you provided into c# with EMGU. You might have to make some alterations since its a slightly different implementation but it should get you started. I also doubt it is a very robust so depending on your specific use it might not be suitable. Best of luck.

```
public List<Rectangle> detectLetters(Image<Bgr, Byte> img)
{
    List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>();
    Image<Gray, Single> img_sobel;
    Image<Gray, Byte> img_gray, img_threshold;
    img_gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
    img_sobel = img_gray.Sobel(1,0,3);
    img_threshold = new Image<Gray, byte>(img_sobel.Size);
    CvInvoke.cvThreshold(img_sobel.Convert<Gray, Byte>(), img_threshold, 0, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    StructuringElementEx element = new StructuringElementEx(3, 17, 1, 6, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_ELEMENT_SHAPE.CV_SHAPE_RECT);
    CvInvoke.cvMorphologyEx(img_threshold, img_threshold, IntPtr.Zero, element, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_MORPH_OP.CV_MOP_CLOSE, 1);
    for (Contour<System.Drawing.Point> contours = img_threshold.FindContours(); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
    {
        if (contours.Area > 100)
        {
            Contour<System.Drawing.Point> contours_poly = contours.ApproxPoly(3);
            rects.Add(new Rectangle(contours_poly.BoundingRectangle.X, contours_poly.BoundingRectangle.Y, contours_poly.BoundingRectangle.Width, contours_poly.BoundingRectangle.Height));
        }
    }
    return rects;
}
```

Usage:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("VfDfJ.png");
List<Rectangle> rects = detectLetters(img);
for (int i=0;i<rects.Count();i++)
    img.Draw(rects.ElementAt<Rectangle>(i),new Bgr(0,255,0),3);
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Display", img.Ptr);
CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0);
CvInvoke.cvDestroyWindow("Display");
```