# error message : no match for call to ‘(cv::Rect) (cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point, cv::Scalar, int)’

Tags: c++, opencv

I have looked quite a bit everywhere and cannot find an answer to my problem.
I tried to replicate a text detection software form this thread ([Extracting text OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv))
but at the end of the code there is a message error saying there is no match for the rectangle even though i have drawn one just above and we enter the loop.
I have tested all the values i could think of and everything seems correct.

here is the complete code ;

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;





int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

namedWindow("source_window2",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("source_window3",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
Mat input = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat in_gray = imread(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat gradient;

Mat Kernelellipse = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3,3));
morphologyEx(in_gray, gradient, MORPH_GRADIENT, Kernelellipse);
Mat thresh;
//on convertit en binaire
threshold(gradient, thresh, 0.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
rectangle(input,Point(0,0),Point(50,50),Scalar(255,255,255),2);
Mat Kernelrectangle = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(9,1));
Mat fermee;
morphologyEx(thresh, fermee, MORPH_CLOSE, Kernelrectangle);
imshow("source_window3", fermee);

Mat noire = Mat::zeros(thresh.size(), CV_8UC1);
//on cheche les contours
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(fermee, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{
    Rect rectangle = boundingRect(contours[i]);
    Mat noirerectangle(noire, rectangle);
    noirerectangle = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
    //on les dessine
    drawContours(noire, contours, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);
    double proportion_de_blanc = (double)countNonZero(noirerectangle)/(rectangle.width*rectangle.height);

    if (proportion_de_blanc > 0.45 && (rectangle.height > 8 && rectangle.width > 8))
    {
        rectangle(input,rectangle.tl(),rectangle.br(),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    }


}
imshow("source_window2",input);





waitKey(0);
return(0);
```

}

My issue is within the last loop :

```
    if (proportion_de_blanc > 0.45 && (rectangle.height > 8 && rectangle.width > 8))
    {
        rectangle(input,rectangle.tl(),rectangle.br(),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    }
```

Comment: **C is not C++ is not C!** Do not add tags at character-match!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined one of your rects as:

```
Rect rectangle = boundingRect(contours[i]);
```

The name *rectangle* collides with the `rectangle` drawing function. So either:

1. rename *rectangle* with another name, such as `Rectangle rect = boundingRect(contours[i]);`
2. call rectangle drawing method as `cv::rectangle(input,rectangle.tl(),rectangle.br(),Scalar(0,255,0),2);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it was indeed my poor choice of variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Rect rectangle = boundingRect(contours[i]);
```

which is creating a variable of type `Rect` named `rectangle`.  Then in your for loop you call what I assume is the `rectangle()` function

```
rectangle(input,rectangle.tl(),rectangle.br(),Scalar(0,255,0),2);
```

In the scope where that call is made the compiler is treating `rectangle` as the variable and not the function.  To fix this you either need to qualify `rectangle` with `cv::` or you can change the name of your variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it and won't make that mistake again!