# OpenCV MSER detect areas from a screenshot - Python

Tags: python, opencv, mser

I saw this example: [OpenCV MSER detect text areas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078625/opencv-mser-detect-text-areas-python/48158475?noredirect=1#comment83296967_48158475)

and I tried to use that code but it's not working.
The error is:

`hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

Where does the variable `p` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That whole construct `[cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]` is called a 'list comprehension'. You can read much more about them in numerous places.

In the code you referred to `regions` is some iterrable, such as a list. This means that when you write `for p in regions` `p` assumes each of the values in `regions`, one at a time. So that's where `p` comes from.

Since `p` is taking part in a list comprehension it can be used in an expression. In this case, the expression is `cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2))`. Thus the value of the entire construct is the value of `cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2))` for each `p` in `regions`.