# Why to reshape MSER contours before detecting texts?

Tags: python, opencv, reshape, text-classification, mser

I am using MSER from opencv-python to detect text using the code from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078625/opencv-mser-detect-text-areas-python). Can anyone help me understand why the contour p is being reshaped to (-1, 1, 2) before computing the convex hull of the objects?

The code is as below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Create MSER object
mser = cv2.MSER_create()

#Your image path i-e receipt path
img = cv2.imread('/home/rafiullah/PycharmProjects/python-ocr-master/receipts/73.jpg')

#Convert to gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

vis = img.copy()

#detect regions in gray scale image
regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(gray)

hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]

cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imshow('img', vis)

cv2.waitKey(0)

mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), dtype=np.uint8)

for contour in hulls:

    cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

#this is used to find only text regions, remaining are ignored
text_only = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow("text only", text_only)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: What is your question? What does `numpy.rehsape()` do? Why is the first argument -1? Or why is `mser.detectRegions()`'s output and `cv2.convexHull()`'s input in different format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It doesn't matter if you reshape or not.**

The reshaping is unnecessary. `cv2.convexHull()` can take either input format. The following images show that the results are the same whether the `contours` in `regions` are reshaped or not.

```
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
hulls1 = [cv2.convexHull(p) for p in regions]
```

[image: they are the same]

This is how the `p` contour changes when it is reshaped:

```
>>> p
array([[305, 382],
       [306, 382],
       [308, 380],
       [309, 380]...


>>> p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
array([[[305, 382]],    
       [[306, 382]],    
       [[308, 380]],    
       [[309, 380]]...
```

Comment: There's not much difference in this image, but it may have some different contour regions in other images, though I have not tested it on other images.