# how to use CV_RETR_CCOMP and CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE in Java OpenCV 3.2.0

Tags: java, c++, opencv3.1

I am new to **OpenCV**. I am converting C++ code into Java code. By referencing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv/23672571#23672571).

While doing this I came across this line:

```
findContours(connected, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP,
             CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

`CV_RETR_CCOMP` and `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` not found in Java OpenCV 3.2.0.

Any reference link or any tutorial regarding this would be great help.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: According to the doc for 3.0, you just need to use the name without the "CV_", i.e. `RETR_CCOMP` and `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
 Imgproc.findContours([here you put your input image/live], contours, hierarchy , Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

If it didn't work for you, you can ask and I'll try to help.