# Processing scanned image using OpenCV Library after scanning it (iOS swift)

Tags: c++, ios, swift, xcode, opencv

I am trying to process scanned Image using OpenCV in iOS (Swift) but I am not getting clear Image after scanning it

Reference of below code is taken from here :- [Scanned Document - Text & Background clarity not good using OpenCV + iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997681/scanned-document-text-background-clarity-not-good-using-opencv-ios)

Below are the images that shows result comparison between the quality of image before and after scanning it. And the result is same, no enhanced quality in After processing image.

Image before processing

[image]

Image After Processing

[image]

Here is my code for scanning image.

```
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage3:(cv::Mat)image
{
//    NSString *foo = path;
//    std::string bar = std::string([image UTF8String]);
    cv::Mat input = image;
//    cv::imread(image,IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    int maxdim = input.cols; //std::max(input.rows,input.cols);
    const int dim = 1024;
    if ( maxdim > dim )
    {
        double scale = (double)dim/(double)maxdim;
        cv::Mat t;
        cv::resize( input, t, cv::Size(), scale,scale );
        input = t;
    }
    if ( input.type()!=CV_8UC4 )
        CV_Error(CV_HAL_ERROR_UNKNOWN,"!bgr");
    cv::Mat result;
    input.copyTo( result ); // result is just for drawing the text rectangles

    // as previously...
    cv::Mat median;
    // remove highlight pixels e.g., those from debayer-artefacts and noise
    cv::medianBlur(input,median,5);
    cv::Mat localmax;
    // find local maximum
    cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT,cv::Size(15,15) );
    cv::morphologyEx( median,localmax,cv::MORPH_CLOSE,kernel,cv::Point(-1,-1),1,cv::BORDER_REFLECT101 );

    std::vector< cv::Rect > bb;
    // detectLetters by @William, modified to internally do the grayscale conversion if necessary
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv?rq=1
      std::vector<cv::Rect> letterBBoxes1=detectLetters(input);
//    detectLetters( input, bb );
    // compose a simple Gaussian model for text background (still assumed white)
    cv::Mat mask( input.size(),CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar( 0 ) );
    if ( bb.empty() )
        return image; // TODO; none found
    for ( size_t i=0;i<bb.size(); ++i )
    {
        cv::rectangle( result, bb[i], cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2,8 ); // visualize only
        cv::rectangle( mask, bb[i], cv::Scalar( 1 ), -1 ); // create a mask for cv::meanStdDev
    }
    cv::Mat mean,dev;
    cv::meanStdDev( localmax, mean, dev, mask );
    if ( mean.type()!=CV_64FC1 || dev.type()!=CV_64FC1 || mean.size()!=cv::Size(1,3) || dev.size()!=cv::Size(1,3) )
        CV_Error(CV_HAL_ERROR_UNKNOWN, "should never happen");
    double minimum[3];
    double maximum[3];
    // simply truncate the localmax according to our simple Gaussian model (+/- one standard deviation)
    for ( unsigned int u=0;u<3;++u )
    {
        minimum[u] = mean.at<double>(u ) - dev.at<double>( u );
        maximum[u] = mean.at<double>(u ) + dev.at<double>( u );
    }
    for ( int y=0;y<mask.rows;++y){
        for ( int x=0;x<mask.cols;++x){
            cv::Vec3b & col = localmax.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
            for ( unsigned int u=0;u<3;++u )
            {
                if ( col[u]>maximum[u] )
                    col[u]=maximum[u];
                else if ( col[u]<minimum[u] )
                    col[u]=minimum[u];
            }
        }
    }
    // do the per pixel gain then
    cv::Mat dst;
    input.copyTo( dst );
    for ( int y=0;y<input.rows;++y){
        for ( int x=0;x<input.cols;++x){
            const cv::Vec3b & v1=input.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
            const cv::Vec3b & v2=localmax.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
            cv::Vec3b & v3=dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
            for ( int i=0;i<3;++i )
            {
                double gain = 255.0/(double)v2[i];
                v3[i] = cv::saturate_cast<unsigned char>( gain * v1[i] );
            }
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @eldesgraciado the image after processing should be clear... like cam scanner app like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997681/scanned-document-text-background-clarity-not-good-using-opencv-ios

Comment: It should do something visible though. Hmm. Maybe you could copy the `dst` image into the native output frame to make sure it takes affect. And you could hand set `gain=4.0` in the innermost loop to emphasize that. Or paste hand written image without the decoration so we can try it.