# Extracting text OpenCV Contours

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I tried doing ocr of each individual contour using tesseract but not getting proper text out of it. Contour Identification is done properly by using [Extracting text OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv/51436780#51436780).
Please suggest.

Comment: Do image normalization and morphological operations to equalize the image and reduce noise from the image. Then if you follow contour process,it helps to give proper result.

Comment: If possible, share the image for better understanding about your problem

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, yes I did morphological operations but not giving proper results though. I did erosion followed by dilation then located contours and extracted the contour blocks. After extracting these blocks, I'm processing the same for tesseract-ocr but not giving proper text for most of the blocks. I took image from the above link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting proper text from OCR because of bad image pre-processing.
Try various image processing techniques to narrow down on a workable approach for your image.
As you have asked under python, If you have a colour image,

1. Convert it into black and white image, to remove the colour noise.

   img = cv2.imread('name_of_the_coloured_input_image',0)
2. Blur the image using blurring techniques of opencv (averaging, gaussian blurring, median blurring and bilateral filtering), this decreases various noises in the image.
   [Please refer to this link and try out various techniques](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)
3. Then use thresholding (simple, adaptive or otsu thresholding), which removes all the pixels which are less than a certain threshold.
   [Please refer to this link and try out various techniques](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Now, get contours and try using tesseract on the contours to get better results.

**Note** : Please remember that for tesseract to work, you should have the text in black against a white background.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have posted my steps in below answer, please check and let me know the improvement points.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the below function, tell me if anything is missing.

```
#gray out the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#image blurring
blur = cv2.blur(gray,(1,1))
cv2.imshow('Blur', blur)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#threshold & invert
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
thresh_copy = thresh.copy()
cv2.imshow("Threshold", thresh_copy)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Erosion
kernel1 = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
img_erosion = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel1, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow("Erosion", img_erosion.copy())
cv2.waitKey(0)

#applying dilation
kernel = np.ones((6,10), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img_erosion.copy(), kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow("Dilation", img_dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#find contours
im2, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

return ctrs
```

Comment: Try with `adaptive threshold` instead of `threshold` and `kernel1`  structuring element can be replaced  with `MORPH_RECT` of `Size(12, 3)` followed by `morphologyEx` can be used before `findContours` process.

Comment: I tried using adaptive threshold as well, I'm able to find the exact contours, but while processing these extracted contours to tesserract I'm getting weird result out of it.

Comment: You can do horizontal and vertical line detection before contour process, that filter out irreverent objects from the image.  See this link [https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html]