# how to extract characters after ostu`s binarisation and adaptive thresholding?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I want to extract the text of the following image(image-1)

[image: i want to extract text from this image]

After applying ostu`s binarisation and adaptive thresholding, it converts the image(image-2) into black and white.I am stuck how to extract characters from this black and white image.

[image: this is the result after applying ostu method and adaptive threshold.]

here is the code for the above

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread("puberty.jpg", 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
print("Threshold selected : ", ret)
cv2.imwrite("./pu.jpg", thresh)


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
data = pytesseract.image_to_string("pu.jpg", lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)
```

i am using pytessract to extract the characters but it does work.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv/51436780#51436780. I know it's in C++ but generally the API transfers pretty well.

Comment: Since the text overlaps, but is in different colors, I would suggest using inRange() to threshold each different color. Then combine the thresholded images or find the text characters for each color separately.