# ValueError while using cv2.findContours() OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect the characters of car's license plate. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731810/segmenting-license-plate-characters/30416054#30416054) yesterday, but when I run the program I get this error:

```
   contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgBWcopy.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
ValueError: too many values to unpack"
```

Why? Does anybody have different way to detect characters?

Comment: Evidently `cv2.findContours` returns more than three values. Perhaps you should figure out what they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the examples in the [documentation](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html), `cv2.findContours()` returns 3 values and you must declare variables to store exactly 3 values.

> See, there are three arguments in cv2.findContours() function, first
>   one is source image, second is contour retrieval mode, third is
>   contour approximation method. And it outputs the **image, contours and**
>   **hierarchy**. contours is a Python list of all the contours in the image.
>   Each individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of
>   boundary points of the object.

```
image,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgBWcopy.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: oh thank you that's work !!! now , how can i recognize the characters and put them to a string value ... like "756jwb" for exp @anmol_uppal

Comment: Didn't the answer linked in your question helped you ?

Comment: the title is 'segmenting' , but i can't find any way for this .... just converting picture with homomorphic or threshold @anmol_uppal

Comment: you will find a lot of useful information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706118/read-numbers-and-letters-from-an-image-using-opencv

Comment: thanks but that is C Language :( ... i want python and opencv @anmol_uppal

Comment: I am sorry @ArashHatami But You will never get code just appropriate to you for such complicated problems, You will only get reference and then you need to work on it, Who knows you could be the first to implement this with Python. :D