# How to create sprites from single images?

Tags: java, image

I need a solution to create one big image with sprites from ~100 single images periodically without intervention because the number of images and the images itself are changing over time. To create the sprites with e.g. http://css-sprit.es/ or any other toolu with a GUI would not be feasible.

Each image has a different width and height. Images formats are png, gif, jpg. My approach would be write a custom java program to concatenate the images vertically into one big image and create a json file to provide the coordinates for later processing. A google search returned me this java awt based tutorial:
https://sites.google.com/site/javagamescorner/home/creating-sprites

Is there another way you would recommend to create sprites? There are a lot of (too?) complex tools and libraries and maybe there is an easier solution.

This Stackoverflow thread mentions a lot of java libraries: [open source image processing lib in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407113/open-source-image-processing-lib-in-java/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention Swing or SWT, I'm going to give you a SWT approach.

Engineer an `ImageBuilder`. Follow the builder pattern, and design it so that it suits your needs. Extend it from `CompositeImageDescriptor` (if you look at the class' APIs, you'll instantly figure out how to draw the images) to work with `ImageDescriptor`s, construct your sprite, then eventually cache the result so it can be used later on.