# Scaling image in java

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I have a requirements to create a web service that will generate user's icon based on their initials. Similar to [this](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable) Android project but on the server side using Java.

[image]

The size of that image should be dynamic. I already have the code that will create a rectangle with two letters in the middle but it is not scaling the text.

Here is my code so far:

```
public BufferedImage getAbbreviationImage(int height, int width, String abbreviation) throws IOException {

    int centerX = width/2;
    int centerY = height/2;

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 90);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);

    g.setColor(Color.decode("#3f404c"));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);


    // get the bounds of the string to draw.
    FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    Rectangle stringBounds = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(abbreviation, g).getBounds();

    FontRenderContext renderContext = g.getFontRenderContext();
    GlyphVector glyphVector = font.createGlyphVector(renderContext, abbreviation);
    Rectangle visualBounds = glyphVector.getVisualBounds().getBounds();

    // calculate the lower left point at which to draw the string. note that this we
    // give the graphics context the y corridinate at which we want the baseline to
    // be placed. use the visual bounds height to center on in conjuction with the
    // position returned in the visual bounds. the vertical position given back in the
    // visualBounds is a negative offset from the basline of the text.
    int textX = centerX - stringBounds.width/2;
    int textY = centerY - visualBounds.height/2 - visualBounds.y;

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(abbreviation, textX, textY);

    g.dispose();

    return bufferedImage;
}
```

Is there any Java library that can do something like this already so that I don't have to write my own code. If not, then what would be the best approach to scale text based on the image size?

Credits:
Some of my code was take from [HERE](https://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/drawing-text-about-its-visual-center/)

Comment: Use the font metrics to calculate the required font size to fit the text in the rectangle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407113/open-source-image-processing-lib-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the size of the font which you attach to the Graphics2D object. From the oracle docs:

```
public abstract void drawString(String str,
              int x,
              int y)
```

> Renders the text of the specified String, using the current text
>   attribute state in the Graphics2D context

You should set the size of the font you use appropriately to match the dimensions of the rectangle. Something like this:

```
int lFontSize = 90 * (originalRectangleWidth / newRectangleWidth);
Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, lFontSize );
```

where:

- 90 is the reference font size (this is what you are setting in the example)
- originalRectangleWidth would be the size of the rectangle you use when the font looks good with size 90
- newRectangleWidth would be the new rectangle width

References:
[Graphics2D (oracle ref)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)
[Font (oracle ref)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)